# Accessing nested LDAP roles in Oracle Internet Directory (OID) within Grails and SpringSecurity

Tags: grails, spring-security, ldap

In our LDAP directory, we have users, who are mapped to groups.  Those groups may be mapped to other groups.  For example:

```
cn=group1,cn=groups,dc=example,dc=com
    uniquemember cn=user1,cn=user,dc=example,dc=com
cn=group2,cn=groups,dc=example,dc=com
    uniquemember cn=user2,cn=user,dc=example,dc=com
    uniquemember cn=group1,cn=user,dc=example,dc=com
```

So User1 belongs to Group1, but User2 belongs to Group2, which in turn belongs to Group1

Within Grails, User1 has authority to Group1, but User2 only has authority to Group2.  From what I've seen, there is no way to cause it to recursively look at the tree.  Realistically, I probably only need a 2 level hierarchy, but even that doesn't seem to work.

I'm attempting to work through the Custom UserDetailsContextManager to see if I can iterate over the initial results and re-query LDAP by group, but I thought I'd see if there was an easier/better way.

Comment: This question has a misleading description/example.  It states "So User1 belongs to Group1, but User2 belongs to Group2, which in turn belongs to Group1" suggesting that `user2` should belong to `group1`.  This is the wrong way around - `group1` is a member of `group2` (via the `uniquemember` attribute, so the correct inclusions is that `group2` includes `user2`, `group1` and therefore `user1`.  The following paragraph also needs correction. The `uniquemember` attribute shows which objects are members of this group, not which objects this object is a member of.

Answer (score 1):

You probably already saw this, but this is from the documentation:

// If you don't want to support group membership recursion (groups in groups), then use the following setting
// grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchFilter = 'member={0}' // Active Directory specific

// If you wish to support groups with group as members (recursive groups), use the following
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchFilter = '(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0})' // Active Directory specific

http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-ldap/docs/manual/guide/2.%20Usage.html

Comment: Yes, I did see that, but as you might notice from the comment, it's Active Directory specific.  I'm using Oracle Internet Directory--and I did try the AD query against it, but it didn't work.  Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle OID has a [product-specific extension](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/oid.1111/e10029/grp_admin.htm) for traversing the hierarchy, known as `CONNECT_BY`, which has LDAP OID `2.16.840.1.113894.1.8.3` .  You can add this as a request control to ask the server to connect/follow hierarchies according to an attribute you specify.  This can be done using both a Java LDAP client program, or using something like OpenLDAP `ldapsearch`, although the set-up is a little tricky.

If you want to use Java to follow the hierarchy, [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/id-mgmt/learnmore/oid-demos-182820.html) contains a [sample program](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/id-mgmt/learnmore/sampleconnectby-350418.zip) which shows how to setup the required `javax.naming.ldap.Control` implementation class, in this case named `ConnectByControl`.

You can also perform this sort of hierarchical search using `ldapsearch`, but it requires some preparation and implied understanding of the required control value, as the value is concatenated then base64-encoded.  The value is in two-parts - the follow-me depth (0=unlimited), followed by the connect-by attribute name (in this case, `uniquemember` is the desired name).  Set the baseDN in your query to the entry where you want to start the hierarchical search.

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://myoidserver.mycompany.com:389 -e 2.16.840.1.113894.1.8.3=MBECAQAEDHVuaXF1ZW1lbWJlcg== -b cn=some_group_containing_groups_nested_by_uniquemember,cn=some_groups,dc=mycompany,dc=com "(objectClass=*)" dn uniquemember
```

The `-e 2.16.840.1.113894.1.8.3=` adds the `CONNECT_BY` request control.  The value, `MBECAQAEDHVuaXF1ZW1lbWJlcg==`, is ASN.1 BER-encoded then base64-encoded value `0uniquemember`, for the depth and attribute-name mentioned above.  This will print first the `dn` for `cn=some_group_containing_groups_nested_by_uniquemember,...` and its direct (user) `uniquemember`s, then each `uniquemember` will be "connected" or followed.  If that entry itself has a set of `uniquemember`, i.e. it is a nested group, the process will continue until leaf/user entries are reached that have no nested `uniquemember`s.